# Arithmetic Progression - the sum of the first 20 terms is 590

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The sum of the first 20 terms is 590 in a arithmetic progression, what is the first term and the 20th term?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: I divided 590 by 20 and multiplied by two to get the sum of the 1st and 20term and got 59 but i dont know what to do after that

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the first term and $d$ the difference of the progression. The first 20 terms are $x,x+d,\dots,x+19d$. Their sum is $20x+190d$, so $20x+190d=590$.

On the other hand, the sum of the first and the 20th term is $2x+19d$. Can you find this value based on the above?

Comment: 59? ... im not sure

Comment: Why are you not sure?

Comment: Ok i just understood now what you did, im slow minded

Comment: No worries! It's good to take time to go through the steps by yourself.